# Retrieving Hyperlink from one Cell to set in another

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Good Evening,

I am looking to retrieve a hyperlink from one cell in one sheet to add it to another cell in a different sheet.  Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
 comment_date = .Cells(row, 3)
 comment_name1 = .Cells(row, col_comments)
 comment1 = .Cells(row, col_comments + 1)
 comment_link1 = .Cells(row, col_comments + 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
 MsgBox ("Link 1: " & comment_link1)
 If (Len(comment_name1) > 0 And Len(comment1) > 0) Then
      row_new = row_new + 2
      comment_sheet.Cells(row_new, 2).Value = comment_date
      comment_sheet.Cells(row_new, 3).Value = comment_name1
      comment_sheet.Cells(row_new, 4).Value = comment1
      comment_sheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(comment_sheet.Cells(row_new, 4).Address), comment_link1
 End If
```

VBA does not like the line of code

```
comment_link1 = .Cells(row, col_comments + 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

What is the right way to retrieve the hyperlink for the cell .Cells(row, col_comments + 1)?

To add the hyperlink to the new cell in the new sheet, is this right?

```
comment_sheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range(comment_sheet.Cells(row_new, 4).Address), comment_link1
```

This seems to put the hyperlink in random locations in the destination sheet.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does Excel *say* about your problem line?  Always useful to include the actual error message.  And your variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The address a hyperlink links to is held in `SubAddress`, not `Address`.  And the text displayed in the cell is held in `TextToDisplay`

So use

```
comment_sheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
  Anchor:=comment_sheet.Cells(row_new, 4), _
  Address:="", _
  SubAddress:=.Cells(row, col_comments + 1).Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress, _
  TextToDisplay:=.Cells(row, col_comments + 1).Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay
```

Comment: For that line of code I get a Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range.

Comment: VBA gives the Run-Time error '9' for this: .Cells(row, col_comments + 1).Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress.

Comment: Make sure cell `.Cells(row, col_comments + 1)` has a hyperlink.  (You didn't post the part of your code that sets `row` and `col_comments`)

Comment: The cell doesn't always have a hyperlink. But row and col_comments are set. That code was working before I added the hyperlink lines.

Comment: If a cell doesn't have a hyperlink then accessing Cell().Hyperlinks(1) will fail.  Wrap the hyperlink stuff in `If Cell(...).Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then`